# Converting blob picture for my word document

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word

I am using XSL - XML for creating dynamicaly a word document with some data from a database.

When I put in my xsl `<w:pict>` with an image in (I think) bytearray with this code:

```
<w:binData w:name="wordml://02000001.jpg" xml:space="preserve">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB....
```

I get the image.

But in my database I have a blob field that represents the picuture. That doesn't look like the bytearray above. How can I convert the blob field of my database to something that can be interpreted by my xsl and put the image in the word document.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the `w:binData` looks to me like it's encoded in base64, so you need to use whatever facility your programming language provides (you don't say in the question which language or tool you're using) to encode the content of your database BLOB as base64 and insert that at the appropriate place in the output.

Comment: Yes, this is Base64 and most likely JPEG. +1

Comment: I use xsl with a descriptor that gets the information of my database with a MySql query. I get the information of my database with <xsl:value-of select="@foto"/> But this aren't base64 characters. I want to convert the blob data of my database into (as you said) base64.

Comment: @Bigjo to be able to give you any specific help I'd have to see some combination of (a) the actual XML that your stylesheet is operating on and/or (b) the code you're using to extract data from the DB and turn it into XML.  I suspect that any necessary conversion would have to be done as part of (b).